# Service Broker getting Automatically Disabled

Tags: sql-server-2005, service, notifications, service-broker

As we know the Service Broker is enabled for the new databases we create. But recently the service broker got disabled automatically. Even if the database was restored shouldnt the Service Broker be enabled by default?

Answer (score 2):

How did you do the restore?  During the restore service broker is disabled by default.

Try doing

```
   RESTORE DATABASE <database_name>  FROM  <backup_device> with ENABLE_BROKER
```

THe above command is fully explained on [MSDN RESTORE Arguments (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx)